# Angular RxJS: Do something when an observable is subscribed or unsubscribed

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm translating some `Javascript` events to `Observables` using `RxJS` in an `Angular` app (`Ionic` framework). I want to start listening to the events when the "client" calls .subscribe(), and stop listening for them when he calls .unsubscribe(). I've looked at the documentation of the `Observable` class, but I wasn't able to see how to do that.

So, assuming there were "onSubscribe" and "onUnsubscribe" methods, I'd like to do something like this:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

...

on(name: string) : Observable<Event> {
    let observable = new Subject<any>();

    observable.onSubscribe(() => {
         this.addEventListener(name, (event) => {
             observable.next(event);
         });
    });

    observable.onUnsubscribe(() => {
        this.removeEventListener(name);
    });

    return observable;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to extend Observable class.

Answer (score -2):

```js
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

...

const unsubscribe;

on(name: string) : Observable<Event> {
    let observable = new Subject<any>();
    // subscribe method returns unsubscribe function, so you have to save in some varibale then call it.
    this.unsubscribe = observable.subscribe(() => {
         this.addEventListener(name, (event) => {
             observable.next(event);
         });
    });

    return observable;
}

// some where else you can do this
unsubscribe();
```